# Eloquent Javascript Chapter 5 Exercise 1

Tags: javascript

The challenge was to take a simple array:

```
var arrays = [[1,2,3],[4,5],[6]];
```

And use reduce/concat to create a single array containing all values and log to the console i.e. [1,2,3,4,5,6] so I produced:

```
console.log(arrays.reduce(function(flat, current) {
  return flat.concat(current);
}));
```

Totally works but on checking their solution they have one little difference:

```
console.log(arrays.reduce(function(flat, current) {
  return flat.concat(current);
}, []));
```

What does the [ ] parameter do in the reduce function, and is it a problem that I left it out?

Comment: initialValue: Optional. Value to use as the first argument to the first call of the callback. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) has the option of being passed an initial value. In their solution, they provide an empty array so the rest of your values can be added from there.

However, yours works because `reduce` uses the first value in the array as the initial value if one isn't given.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) (note that `previousValue` is the first argument in the callback, `currentValue` is the second argument):

> The first time the callback is called, `previousValue` and `currentValue` can be one of two values. If `initialValue` is provided in the call to reduce, then `previousValue` will be equal to `initialValue` and `currentValue` will be equal to the first value in the array. If no `initialValue` was provided, then `previousValue` will be equal to the first value in the array and `currentValue` will be equal to the second.

Answer (score 5):

Initial value.

The difference appears in two cases:

- You version will crash if `arrays` is empty array. Theirs won't.
- If `arrays` contains the single array, you get that instance, but they copy it into a new one.